# NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread on MonoMac?

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, monomac

Does "MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread" exist in MonoMac??  It does in MonoTouch.  I need this for MessageBox threading issues....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does! [Here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoMac.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread%28MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector%2cMonoMac.Foundation.NSObject%29) is a link to the API documentation for it.

Comment: Dang i'm stupid.  I guess I need to take a break from the computer.  I only looked at the static methods.... guess I would have to create an instance dur :=}